# javafx and css code to change hyperlink color on mouse hover

Tags: css, hyperlink, javafx, mouseevent

I am working with java fxml application and i have one hyperlink, I want to change its color when mouse is over it and again revert back when mouse is exited from it. Can any body post some code to achieve it. I tried some css code but not working,

```
On mouse entered:-
 @FXML
    private void changeCloseColorToWhite() {
        hypLnkClose.setStyle("-fx-color: white;");
    }

On mouse exited:-
@FXML
    private void changeCloseColorToBrown() {
        hypLnkClose.setStyle("-fx-color: #606060;");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm

Answer (score 3):

Setting style in java code is heavy on the application. I would suggest defining this in the CSS file. try something like this below to fulfill what you need:

```
.hyperlink:hover {
    -fx-underline: true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can also do like this
your_file.fxml(This is you .fxml file)
<Hyperlink text="you text to being hyperlink" styleClass="myLink">


your_style.css(This is your styleSheet file)

.myLink{
   -fx-text-fill: white;
       }
.myLink:hover{
   -fx-text-fill: #606060;
        }

This will also work fine. So try it
```